# Bluetooth 16bit UUID registrar is running out of IDs available for companies/members?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

Out of curiosity I was inspecting the official registrar of 16bit UUIDs:

```
https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf
```

Is it me or is the number-space reserved for companies running out. What I mean to say is that even though 16bits are enough for 65536 numbers, in the document we see that company-ids start from 0xFCDC (64732) and up.

The greatest company-id seems to be 0xFEFF (=65279 held by 'GN Netcom'. So there seem to be only around 244 IDs left to be bought.

If those 244 IDs are exhausted what will the Bluetooth SIG do? Expand to 32bit or try to recycle 16bit IDs that have already been used by companies which have vanished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken. This list grows downwards and the 16-bit UUID for Members *0xFEFF GN Netcom* is the first one that was registered. The latest entry is *0xFCDC Amazon.com Services, LLC*, so I assume that there is still plenty of room for the next years. And last but not least, a fee of $3,000 USD is charged for registering a 16-bit UUID.